# Gelfand Triples / Rigged Hilbert Spaces - Reflexivity necessary?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, adjoint-operators

There have been several questions asked on various aspects of Gelfand triples. However, I have not yet found an answer to the following question:

Let $V$ be a Banach space, $H$ be a Hilbert space such that we have a dense embedding
$$
i :V \hookrightarrow H.
$$
We then consider the "adjoint map"
$$
i^{*} : H^{*} \rightarrow V^{*}
$$
which is defined via
$$
_{V^{*}}\langle i^{*}(\phi), v \rangle_{V} :=~ _{H^{*}} \langle \phi, i(v) \rangle_{H}
$$
(intuitively, if $V \subset H$ as sets, one can think of the action of $i^{*}$ as being the restriction of a functional on $H$ to a functional on $V$).

We would like this map $i^{*}$ to have three properties:

1. continuous
2. injective
3. with dense image, i.e. $i^{*}(H^{*}) \subset V^{*}$ is a dense subset w.r.t. the norm on $V^{*}$.

If we have established this, we can proceed to find the Gelfand triple 
$$
V \hookrightarrow H \equiv H^{*} \hookrightarrow V^{*}
$$ 
with dense embeddings.

The first property is easy to check, the second follows from the density of $i$. However, for the third property, one needs (or rather: seems to need) something more. Brezis, in his functional analysis book, for example, assumes **reflexivity** (Rem. 5.2.3 on p. 136 in the 2011 edition) and so do Liu/Röckner (*SPDEs: An Introduction*, Ch. 4.1, p. 69), Zeidler (*Linear Monotone Operators*, Ch. 23.4, p. 416) and all other books I could get my hands on.

As I will show below, reflexivity is sufficient indeed, but here is my *question*: **Is reflexivity also necessary for property 3?**

That it works if $V$ is assumed to be reflexive can be seen as follows: Let $c$ denote the canonical map
$$
c : V \rightarrow V^{**}, ~ v \mapsto \psi_{v}, ~ \psi_{v}(v^{*}) := v^{*}(v),
$$
i.e. $c(v)(v^{*}) := v^{*}(v)$. If $V$ is reflexive, $c$ is surjective. Now to prove the density of $i^{*}(H^{*}) \subset V^{*}$ we need to check that if a continuous functional $\psi$ on $V^{*}$, i.e. $\psi \in V^{**}$, is zero on the image, then it must already be the zero functional, i.e. $\psi = 0$. So the condition we need to check is
$$
_{V^{**}} \langle \psi, i^{*}(\phi) \rangle_{V^{*}} = 0 \quad \forall \phi \in H^{*} \quad \Rightarrow \quad \psi = 0.
$$
By reflexivity, $\psi = c(v)$ for a $v \in V$. So let $\phi \in H^{*} 
$ be arbitrary. By the definition of $c$ and $i^{*}$ we get
\begin{align*}
0 &= ~_{V^{**}} \langle \psi, i^{*}(\phi) \rangle_{V^{*}} = ~_{V^{**}} \langle c(v), i^{*}(\phi) \rangle_{V^{*}} = ~_{V^{*}} \langle i^{*}(\phi), v \rangle_{V} \\
&= ~_{H^{*}} \langle \phi, i(v) \rangle_{H}.
\end{align*}
Since this holds true for every $\phi \in H^{*}$, by Hahn-Banach (or rather, since $H^{*}$ separates points on $H$), this implies $i(v) = 0$ which by the injectivity of $i$ yields $v = 0$ and hence by linearity of $c$ that $\psi = c(v) = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the triple $V=l^1$, $H=l^2$, $V^*=l^\infty$. However, the closure of $l^2$ with respect to the $l^\infty$-norm is $c_0$, which is a closed and proper subspace of $l^\infty$. Hence, the embedding $i^*$ fails to have dense image. This proves that there is some non-reflexive $V$, where the claim fails.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But isn't the space $V = L^{3}(\Omega)$ a reflexive Banach space?

Comment: @Andre yes you are right! this was stupid..

Comment: I do not see how this provides an answer to the question "Is reflexivity also necessary for property 3?".

Comment: @gerw it just shows that reflexivity is not assumed due to lazyness ;)